# gnsdk python wrapper - get track position from stream

Tags: gracenote

album.match_position() consistently returns 0 regardless of where in the song the clip is from.

Is there something else needed for this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, it will be fixed in the next release. Unfortunately we don't have a release date for that at this time.